# The second tap on UITextField (within a UITableViewCell subclass) unexpectedly dismisses the keyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I'm implementing a UITableView that holds a few custom UITableViewCells, each of which contains UITextField.

Unlike most people who want a keyboard to disappear upon some events, I want it to appear all the time.
The issue is that the first tap on UITextField triggers a keyboard to appear without any problems. But once I tap on it again the keyboard that currently appears now disappears.

Moreover, another related issue is I cannot change the cursor's position inside UITextField.
Once I hold the tap on UITextField in order to change the cursor's current position, the magnifying glass pops up as expected. But once I let go the tap, the keyboard closes immediately.

How do I solve this problem?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...
    TagDetailCell *cell1 = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TagDetailCellView" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
    TagDetailCell *cell2 = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TagDetailCellView" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
    TagDetailCell *cell3 = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TagDetailCellView" owner:self options:nil] lastObject]; 
    self.cells=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:cell1, cell2, cell3, nil];
    ...
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell=[self.cells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        ...
        ((TagDetailCell*)cell).fieldLabel.text= ...;
        ((TagDetailCell*)cell).fieldValue.clearButtonMode=UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
        ((TagDetailCell*)cell).fieldValue.text=...;
        [((TagDetailCell*)cell).fieldValue addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
        ...
    }
    return cell;

}
```

I didn't implement any delegates of UITextField. Should I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was stupid. I subclass UITextField and override the following method in order to prevent user from copying/pasting texts:

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender    
{    
    [UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuVisible = NO;  //do not display the menu
    [self resignFirstResponder];                      //do not allow the user to selected anything
    return NO;
}
```

The problem of keyboard dismissing came from the call of `[self resignFirstResponder]`.  Removing it, therefore, solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `UIViewController` method `disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal` in the docs.
Quoted for Apple docs:

> Override this method in a subclass to allow or disallow the dismissal
>   of the current input view (usually the system keyboard) when changing
>   from a control that wants the input view to one that does not. Under
>   normal circumstances, when the user taps a control that requires an
>   input view, the system automatically displays that view. Tapping in a
>   control that does not want an input view subsequently causes the
>   current input view to be dismissed but may not in all cases. You can
>   override this method in those outstanding cases to allow the input
>   view to be dismissed or use this method to prevent the view from being
>   dismissed in other cases.

Comment: Thank you for useful information. I haven't known this before. However, the keyboard still disappears even after I return `YES` in `disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal`. Setting presentation style to `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` also doesn't help.

Comment: I tried to make sure that `disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal` is called properly, but this function does not get called at all. Any idea?

Comment: Try setting the `UITextField`'s delegate to your view controller.